# Value of integer changes between call and subroutine

Tags: variables, fortran

I'm trying to implement a new subroutine, `inigw`, in a decades-old Fortran-based program, and struggling mightily. I'm a total Fortran beginner so hopefully I'm missing something obvious.

I am calling a subroutine, `inigw(iyear,imonth,iday,nday,time,seed)`. Of the 6 input variables to the call, all are integers except `time`. If I write the variables out immediately before calling, everything looks fine:

```
 if (gwexist.eq.2 .and. iyear.ge.igwyear .and. iyear.le.igwend) then
            write(*,*) 'iyear in call = ', iyear
            write(*,*) 'imonth in call = ', imonth
            write(*,*) 'iday in call = ', iday
            write(*,*) 'nday in call = ', nday
            write(*,*) 'time in call = ', time
            write(*,*) 'seed in call = ', seed
    call inigw (iyear,imonth,iday,nday,time,seed)  
 endif
```

The output looks as I would expect:

```
 iyear in call =         2013
 imonth in call =            1
 iday in call =            4
 nday in call =            4
 time in call =    28800.00    
 seed in call =   1776642162
```

However, the values of all the integers (`iyear`, `imonth`, `iday`, `nday`, and `seed`) are changed within my subroutine.

```
c ---------------------------------------------------------------------
      subroutine inigw (iyear, imonth, iday, nday, time, seed)
c ---------------------------------------------------------------------
c SCZ- 1/31/2014
c This routine is intended to read in hourly depth to groundwater data from 
c text files. Much of the language is borrowed from inimet.               

c Define some variables   
          implicit none

      real 
     >  dtgwin(ndpts),             ! read-in depth to groundwater
     >  time,                      ! time in seconds since start of day
     >  tdomthick                  ! total domain thickness [m]

     integer
     >  seed,
     >  nday,
     >  iyear,                     ! main routine year
     >  imonth,                    ! main routine month
     >  iday,                      ! main routine day
c
      write(*,*) 'iyear in inigw = ', iyear
      write(*,*) 'imonth in inigw = ', imonth
      write(*,*) 'iday in inigw = ', iday
      write(*,*) 'nday in inigw = ', nday
      write(*,*) 'time in inigw = ', time
      write(*,*) 'seed in inigw = ', seed
...
```

The values of the integers are now different, but the real number (`time`) is the same!

```
 iyear in inigw =   2.8208138E-42
 imonth in inigw =   1.4012985E-45
 iday in inigw =   5.6051939E-45
 nday in inigw =   5.6051939E-45
 time in inigw =    28800.00    
 seed in inigw =   3.4667155E+25
```

What's interesting is that there's another subroutine, `inimet`, structured in basically the same way with the same inputs to the call, and the variables pass through that call successfully. I assume I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm not sure exactly what. I've tried Googling and found nothing. Sorry I can't provide a reproducible example- I don't know enough about Fortran to write one.

Comment: Is the "i" in "integer" in the subroutine really in column 6?

Comment: And there's a `,` after the `iday` declaration.  Are you sure this version of the code compiled and that you aren't using a previously built object?

Comment: Another clue that you have a problem with your declarations, as suggested by @francescalus, is that the compiler is outputting your integers as if they are reals.  e.g., `iyear in inigw =   2.8208138E-42`.  That's not FORTRAN output of an integer.  The bits in integer `iyear` were converted to human-readable text assuming that the number is floating point.

Comment: @frances, there were actually a couple more variables after the iday, which is why there was the comma. I deleted them from the example for readability... should have got rid of the comma too! Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are adding a new subroutine to a legacy FORTRAN program, you can use as much of Fortran >=90 as you wish.  Assuming that you have a Fortran >=90 compiler.  For example, you could use the "new" free-form source layout.  And not have to count columns.  You might have to use two compile commands, with different options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough, `time` is the only one that appears to remain unchanged. It's *also* the only one that's not declared in the function with an `integer` statement that appears to begin one column too far to the left.

Fix the indentation of that and your problem should be solved. FORTRAN was one of those languages that was very picky about this sort of thing.

Comment: I assume that's a copy-paste error, as otherwise, with `implicit none` there would be no variable `seed` - just a `tdomthickntegerseed`.

Comment: Stretching my memory here, @francescalus, but implicit none may not affect variables already in existence, such as from the subroutine definition. It seems too much of a coincidence that the integer is misplaced and all vars appear to be reals. In any case, OP simply has to try and let us know. If I'm wrong, I'll delete the answer (and comment so no one else makes the same mistake). But I'm 91% sure I'm right :-)

Comment: It's a very tempting answer, yes.  And the inconsistent indentation of `implicit none` suggests it may not have been in the original code...

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone- it was simply an issue of the integer statement starting in column 6. Learning experience for sure! Now to fix the next bug...

Answer (score 1):

As we've established that the problem was in indentation (see the answer by @paxdiablo) I suppose it won't hurt to elaborate on why.

The code is using fixed-form source code.  This means that a character other than a blank or "0" in column 6 is treated as a *continuation* character.  Your "i" of "integer" is such a character.  This, coupled with the general insignificance of blanks, means that your code snippet

```
      real 
     >  dtgwin(ndpts),             ! read-in depth to groundwater
     >  time,                      ! time in seconds since start of day
     >  tdomthick                  ! total domain thickness [m]

     integer
     >  seed,
     >  nday,
```

is equivalent to

```
      real 
     >  dtgwin(ndpts),             ! read-in depth to groundwater
     >  time,                      ! time in seconds since start of day
     >  tdomthickntegerseed,
     >  nday,
```

(also noting that comments do not affect program interpretation).

So `nday` and the following variables are indeed declared `real`.

Note that there is no variable `seed` or `tdomthick` declared explicitly, so your `implicit none` confuses me as to why your code compiled.  [Even dummy arguments need to be explicitly declared with `implicit none` unless you're using some other form of association to get these variables?]

Finally, I'll echo @M.S.B.'s comment about not writing new code in fixed-form, as I imagine you aren't using an F77-only compiler.